# Dialog in MFC programming

Tags: mfc, dialog

I am learning MFC programming. In the part of dialog design, I entered a problem.
[image: This picture is the screenshot of the dialog class]

The resource is IDD_PEN_WIDTH, which is the ID of the dialog. And there is a piece of automatically generated code related to this:

```
class PenWidthDlg : public CDialogEx
{
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(PenWidthDlg)

public:
    PenWidthDlg(CWnd* pParent = NULL);   // standard constructor
    virtual ~PenWidthDlg();

// Dialog Data
    enum { IDD = IDD_PEN_WIDTH };

protected:
    virtual void DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX);    // DDX/DDV support

    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
public:
    int m_nPenWidth;
};
```

Before I run my program, the IDD_PEN_WIDTH shows "#define IDD_PEN_WIDTH 301" while hovering mouse on IDD_PEN_WIDTH in the code. But when I run it, there is one error says IDD_PEN_WIDTH is an undefined identifier. Then I hover mouse on "IDD_PEN_WIDTH", it also says it's undefined.
I am usually confused in MFC studying, and I will appreciate very much for your detailed explanations. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It has to be defined in every cpp file that uses it. Add #include "Resource.h" in those cpp files. Do that #include before the #include of the dialog .h file.

Comment: Just include the resource header in the header that defines the dialog. You'll need it every time.